# How to query a table from different databases without using alias of database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing task of retrieving the data from both database tables,I included following query to achieve it.

*Query in stored procedure*:

```
--Some query here...
LEFT OUTER JOIN     aaa c 
ON                  l.IDNo      = c.LogonIDNo
INNER JOIN          Data_00.dbo.yyy A
ON                  C.MacCusNo  = A.Cus_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN     abc T 
ON                  A.xyz       = T.bbb
```

*Tables*:

```
aaa : table of database Data_01
yyy : table of database Data_00
```

Is there any way to retrieve the data from both the database tables without using 'Data_00.dbo.yyy' I want to use only `yyy` instead of it.

Comment: why don't you want to use the Data_00.dbo.yyy? If it is in a different database you will have to specify it

Comment: yes sir you r right, but now we want to use same query to fetch data from both the tables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll assume you're using SQL Server.

Yes, you can create a synonym. Synonyms allow you to specify a shorthand name for accessing various database objects, whether they reside in the same database as the synonym rule or not.

```
USE Data_01;

CREATE SYNONYM yyy FOR Data_00.dbo.yyy;
```

Comment: Yes I am using the sql server2008,